# Search Realm Relationship in Swift 3

Tags: swift, realm

*Swift 3, Realm 2.1*

I'm trying to figure out how to search my `Aircraft` objects based on values in its related `fieldValues` list. Here is a simplified view of my class structure:

```
class Aircraft: Object {
  dynamic var makeModel = ""
  let fieldValues = List<FieldValue>()
}

class FieldValue: Object{
  dynamic var name = ""
}
```

I can search the `makeModel` value (where `search!` is my search term) like this:

```
let makeModelPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "makeModel BEGINSWITH[c] %@", search!)
```

...but how do I check to see if `search` matches any `name` values in the `fieldValues` list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query over key paths: `NSPredicate(format: "ANY fieldValues.name = %@", search!)`

Comment: Ah, perfect! I had tried that except I was missing the `ANY` parameter. It's working great now. Thanks a ton!